# For D major, if I use the F# note on the low "E" string, does that count as a D major?

Tags: guitar

For D major, if I use the F# note on the low "E" string, does that count as a D major?﻿ If yes, what would I call this chord?

Answer (score 7):

It certainly is another D major chord. Playing an F# at the bottom of the chord makes it a 1st inversion, commonly written as D/F#. Most people who play this chord would tend to put the thumb over onto bottom string, 2nd fret. You could also play the open chord from the 5th string open (A), which would then be a 2nd inversion, or D/A.

As long as you have all three notes from a simple triad chord, it will be called according to its root note. The order of the notes (especially on guitar!) will only alter the *voicing*.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are talking about on a guitar?  If your bottom note is F# and you include As and Ds above it, then it is called D major, 1st inversion.

Comment: There is a 'guitar' tag under the question!

Answer (score 1):

The chord you refer to is most commonly denoted as a D/F# for which the simplest explanation is a D Major Chord with F# as the lowest (bass) note ("D with F# Bass"). You will often see this type chord notation for guitar referred to as a "slash chord".  In a slash chord the first letter is the chord name (root) and the letter after the slash denotes the bass note (usually the first note strummed) to be played.

Technically a D/F# slash chord is still a D major, but as others have said, it is a first inversion of the D Major Triad.  We also call it a "different voicing" of the D Major chord. All inversions of a D Major Chord on guitar contain the same three notes in the D Maj Triad - except the order that you play them is altered (also the number of times and octaves the note appears/repeats).

The D/F# chord is very useful on guitar when playing a G, D, Em progression as it allows for a nice descending bass line to be incorporated into your progression.  And in some songs, the D/F# voicing just seems to sound better than the basic D major chord played only on the top four strings.

Many folks play the D/F# by using their thumb over the top of the neck to fret the F# on the low E string.  However my hands are too small to reach over with my thumb so I use my index finger on the low E string.  Usually I leave out the pinky and don't play the high e.

The D/F# is one of my favorite alternate voicings of a chord for guitar.  I use it often.